# Any way to make gmsh to use the same vertex set on both sides of a material boundary?

Tags: mesh, numeric, numerical-methods, finite-element-analysis

I am trying to mesh a complex geometry composed of 3 kinds of materials, like below:

[image]

The geometry is imported from a *.stp file.

I defined several physical surfaces and 3 physical domains in the geo file:

```
Physical Surface("air-case", 1) = {50, 42, 41, 40, 48};
Physical Surface("case-thermal", 2) = {32, 15, 22, 21, 25};
Physical Surface("thermal-grain", 3) = {2, 7, 6};
Physical Surface("thermal-fluid", 4) = {30, 27};
Physical Surface("burning", 5) = {3, 4, 5, 10, 13, 9, 11, 12};

Physical Surface("case-sym", 11) = {49, 51, 34, 43, 44, 47};
Physical Surface("thermal-sym", 12) = {24, 28, 14, 23, 29, 33};
Physical Surface("grain-sym", 13) = {8, 1};

Physical Volume("case", 1) = {6, 5, 7};
Physical Volume("thermal", 2) = {2, 3, 4};
Physical Volume("grain",3)={1};
```

The picture looks ok at first glance. The vertices near material boundaries are well aligned, see enlarged views below:

[image]

However, inside the geometry (actually, near the middle of the cylinder part), you can find the vertice are not aligned

[image]

It is wired because, on the boundary of the green and yellow material, all the vertice are aligned. Even though the output mesh contains duplicated points, I can easily remove duplicated ones according to the coordinate. I think this means gmsh  does have the ability to ensure this.

However, near the yellow/blue interface, vertice just randomly distributes on two sides, it is then impossible to connect the vertices without modifying the coordinates.

I think there must be some way to ensure gmsh to use the same vertex on both sides of the interface, but I didn't find relevant information in the document.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that this question would be better suited here: https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @philm I post it here because I found some relevant discussion (about gmsh) in the main stackoverflow site. I'll consider `scicomp` next time ...

Answer (score 7):

OK, I've got the solution somewhere else. I am posting it here to help others who encountered the same issue.

The problem is resulted by my modelling procedure. I modelled the geometry using Creo in separated parts and then exported the assembly. As a result, the *.stp file contains several geometries which are not topologically connected.

To solve this, we need to merge the duplicated surfaces. There are two options:

> You can use the new CAD features in Gmsh to remove these duplicate internal surfaces. With the stable release, you can do

```
SetFactory("OpenCASCADE");
v() = ShapeFromFile("file.step");
BooleanFragments{ Volume{v()}; Delete; }{}
```

> With the latest development snapshots, you can use the "Coherence" shortcut (which does exactly the same thing):

```
SetFactory("OpenCASCADE");
Merge "file.step";
Coherence;
```

The `Coherence` didn't work for my model, but `BooleanFragments` worked perfectly.

Thank professor Geuzaine for offering help.